# Ember-simple-auth ApplicationRoute model function

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have classic setup of Ember-simple-auth, in ApplicationRoute I use

```
model: function () {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    user: this.store.find('gsUser').then(function(data) {
      return data.get('content')[0]
    })
  });
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this.controllerFor('user').set('content', model.user);
}
```

When user losts authorization, and you open the page. ApplicationRoute::model is fired first, server returns 401 and other execution is stopped.

```
GET http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/api/1/users.json 401 (Unauthorized)
Error while loading route: undefined
```

`model` should be fired only when authentication is successfull.

I saw that there is `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` but I've tried all the ways to listen to it, noone worked. How to listen to this event and get data from server when user is successfully authenticated?

11/06 22:57 UPDATE:`enter code here`

One solution for this problem that I've managed to achieve, *but it seems totally not ember way*:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  skipModelLoading: false,

  beforeModel: function() {
    this.set('skipModelLoading', !this.get('session').get('isAuthenticated'));
  },

  model: function () {
    if (this.get('skipModelLoading')) {
      return;
    }

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      user: this.store.find('gsUser').then(function(data) {
        return data.get('content')[0]
      })
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    if (this.get('skipModelLoading')) {
      return;
    }

    this.controllerFor('user').set('content', model.user);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you check that the user is authenticated in the route's `beforeModel` either manually or by mixing in the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` (the latter might be a problem because it would apply to the login route as well then)?

Comment: @marcoow: 

Tried, I can stop transition:

    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        if (!this.get('session').get('isAuthenticated')) {
          transition.abort();
        }
    }

But what to do next? ) Transition to login route works bad, as it is infinite redirect. How it should be done in the right way?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem - you cannot require the session to be authenticated in the application route's `model` method as that would apply to all routes including the login route.

Comment: @marcoow any ideas how to receive User model from server after successfull login & when page might be refreshed? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a more ember-way solution for my problem:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  onSessionIsAuthenticated: function () {
    var isAuthenticated = this.get('session').get('isAuthenticated');

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return false;
    }

    var userController = this.controllerFor('user');

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      user: this.store.find('gsUser').then(function (data) {
        userController.set('content', data.get('content')[0]);
      })
    });
  }.observes('session.isAuthenticated').on('init')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're loading the authenticated user in that `model` method. I'd do it differently and attach that property to the session as shown in this example: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html#L101

Comment: do you have some open-sourced examples that use your library (except those two provided somewhere in repository)? I really struggle to implement it right. For me it seems like I want really simple task to do, I want to listen for success authorization event, but now its like second day of debugging ember.js + ember simple auth to achieve it.. and still no luck (

Comment: There's 9 examples or is included in the repository plus some external ones linked in the README.